# When i try to get my bot status and do node, "Client is not defined"

Tags: discord.js

When i try to get my bot status and do node . console send mi this

```
Client is not defined
```

i am whit handlers and my code is

```
 module.exports = () =>{
   console.log('Бота е активен!'); 
  client.user.setActivity('1. Perfix is , . 2. Гуги е известен! 3. SMP S1 2021! ', { type: 'PLAYING' }, { status: 'dnd' }).catch(console.error);
}
```

Comment: Is "client" imported? It would help to see the whole code.

Comment: {const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client({ prtials: ["MESSAGE", "CHANNEL", "RECTIONS"] });






client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
client.events = new Discord.Collection();
['command_handler', 'event_handler'].forEach(handler =>{
    require(`./handlers/${handler}`)(client, Discord);
})} see

Answer (score 0):

"client" is not available immediately, it's an async operation, so you have to wrap up your code into an event listener similar to this (or have a look at other options in the Discord library)

```
client.on("ready", () => {
    client.user.setActivity('1. Perfix is , . 2. Гуги е известен! 3. SMP S1 2021! ', { type: 'PLAYING' }, { status: 'dnd' }).catch(console.error);
});
```

and basically, the module architecture needs a bit different then to export anything